# Time range when parsing messages in telegram. Telegram Bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telethon

I'm making a Telegram bot and I need to set a time range for collecting messages for the last month.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from datetime import date


api_id = my_id
api_hash = ''
phone = ''

client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
dateStart = date(2022, 12, 27)


async def main():
    async for message in client.iter_messages(-1001369370434, reverse=True, offset_date=dateStart, search='eth'):
        print(message.chat.title, ':', message.date, ':', message.text)

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to get messages for the last month, not for all time

Answer (score 0):

The `offset_date` should be the beginning of the date range.

Then use `reverse=True` to loop from the `offset_date` to today's latest message:

---

My complete test script:

```py
import datetime
import asyncio
import re
from telethon import TelegramClient

CHAT  = 1234567
BEGIN = datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0)

client = TelegramClient('anon', '111111', 'aaaabbbbccccddddeee')
client.start()

async def main():

    chat  = await client.get_input_entity(CHAT)

    async for message in client.iter_messages(chat, reverse=True, offset_date=BEGIN):
        print(message.date, "\t\t", message.text)

client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Which output's all the messages starting `2022-11-1` until today:

```
2022-11-01 00:00:43+00:00        ...
2022-11-01 00:00:59+00:00        ...
2022-11-01 00:01:50+00:00        ...
2022-11-01 00:01:50+00:00        ...
2022-11-01 00:05:32+00:00        ...
2022-11-01 00:08:47+00:00        ...
2022-11-01 00:10:00+00:00        ...
```

Comment: What about search = 'eth'?
and I don't understand this line:
BEGIN = datetime.datetime(2022, FROM_MONTH, 1, 0, 0, 0)

Comment: If I use reverse, it does not work search
async for message in client.iter_messages(chat, reverse=True, offset_date=BEGIN, search='eth'):

Comment: FROM_MONTH was a variable holding the month you want to start from

Comment: When adding a time range (offset_date + reverse=True) the key search (search='') does not work. Without reverse=True everything works. But I need to get messages only from last month, so I choose offset from specific date and reverse. How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Try removing the `search` to ensure the correct date range is given

Comment: Checked it out, everything works fine. But I get all the messages, and I need the key

Comment: I read the api, it says to add the entity= and ids= arguments, but I can't figure out what those are. It's necessary for reverse to work

Comment: My code is working as expected without those.

Comment: Ow I think I see your problem, you'll need `get_input_entity`. I'll post my complete code, gimme a sec

Comment: Yes, your code works just like mine. But it displays all messages and you need the attribute search='' to search by keyword

Comment: we added the entity argument, but to work correctly we need the ids= argument, I don't know what it is

Comment: About reverse, the api says:
"You cannot use this if both entity and ids are None".

Comment: Yea I see, `search` behaves quite different. I never used it like that. I've always looped over each message and did something like `if "eth" in message.text:`

Comment: how to make it happen ?